# Create custom preference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I would like to create a `SeekBarPreference` like preference. I needed range `Seekbar`. Then I found this library: https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar . I would like to create a preference using `CrystalRangeSeekbar` that will have same look as other preferences.

I use compileSdkVersion = 29, minSdkVersion = 23, targetSdkVersion = 29.

Is that even possible on Android? I spent several hours trying to code something, but I never managed to get same look. I need all padding, margins, caption and summary positions, etc. to be same as in built-in preferences.

Is there any official manual to make custom preferences that will have same look as built-in preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a manual on how to do this, but I had a problem where I needed a ranged seekbar preference for minSdkVersion=22 and what was available at the time did not allow a ranged seek until a later SDK version.

So I just made my own, not sure how exactly it looks compared to the built in preferences

The xml layout snippet is used is

```xml
<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/GridLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/fontSeek"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="15"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:max="40"
                android:padding="6dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fontText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:minEms="2"
                android:padding="6dp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

then in the code I adjusted the textview value to show the adjusted range instead of 0 to 40 by adding 20 to the value.

The extracted Java code associated with xml

```java
int fontSize;

int fontSizeOffset = 20;

fontSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                // Work out the correct values
                fontSizeAdjusted = progress;
                fontSize = fontSizeAdjusted + fontSizeOffset;
                // Update the Textview
                fontTextView.setText(String.valueOf(fontSize));
                // store pref
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("fontSize", fontSize);
                editor.apply();
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do Nothing
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        });
```

You might be able to do better now with Androidx https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference but this was not available when I developed this code.

You should be able to tweak the style to match exactly the standard preference as the docs say it is just a seekbar with optional texview.

You can always look at the source for Androidx to see how they do it e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/preference/preference/src/main/java/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference.java

and

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/preference/preference/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar.xml

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by modyfing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/preference/preference/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar.xml and using it like this for my preference: 
        android:layout="@layout/rangeseekbar_preference"